# How to diff cpp files only of 2 directories?

Tags: linux, diff

I am trying to execute diff something like:

```
diff -aru ifm/*.cpp ../ifm/*.cpp 2>&1 | tee ifm.diff
```

It gives me error:

```
diff: extra operand `ifm/ifmArchiveFileReaderWriter.cpp'
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Linux command. Try unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You can only give two filenames to `diff`. You're giving it all the `*.cpp` files in both directories.

Comment: @Barmar: If you specify 2 dirs only, it diffs all files inside those 2 dirs, so i don't think that's true

Comment: That's still just two filename arguments. When you give directories, it recurses into them and compares each corresponding file.

Comment: Remember, wildcards are expanded by the shell, they're not seen by the program. So all the `diff` program sees in your case is a whole bunch of filenames, it has no idea how they should be matched up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running into with the collection of files you are trying to present `diff` with is exactly why `diff` has the ability to scan 2 directories and `diff` common files between the two. It has its own index that keeps track of what files in list a correspond to files in list b. You can't just give `diff` two seemingly unrelated lists of files and expect that it has some sneaky way of discerning that file1.txt in list 1 corresponds to file1.txt in list 2 when they are shuffled between 50 other files. `diff` either compares files or directories.

That doesn't prevent you from organizing many files through arrays or tmp files, and then iterating over the list passing `diff` 2 files at a time that are proper. You just can't throw all of them at `diff` at once and expect diff to do it.

This is where good directory planning can really help insure that you can make use of diff in the way you would like. With two directories you can logically compare, then a good unified diff is a simple way to visualize the differences and at the same time provide patch information to others who can make use of your improvements to the code. A good `diff -uNrw dir dir2 > dir_dir2.diff` is a great way to handle it. Gook luck.